# 3D Viewport Increase Selected Edge Thicknes

Tags: edges, customization, theme

Looking for setting to change Edge thickness. Currently selected edges are to thin and difficult to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's under interface settings in user preferences. See below:

[image: EdgeWidth]

Be warned, however, this also changes the thickness of the grid lines, the outline, and even the edges of some of the UI elements, so maybe enable and disable it as needed. There doesn't seem to be a way to uncouple this effect either, unfortunately.